# replacin data in column taken from other file in condition that.., python

Tags: python, text, conditional-statements

In my large dataset i have one column with names like this:

main file:

```
1, NAME1
2, NAME2
3, NAME2
   ...
```

all i need is, to create 3rd column with surnames, with some conditions.
I have 2 text files with single words(SURNAME1.txt, SURNAME2.txt). I need to create condition where i can use it to create 3rd column, for example:

```
if NAME1 in 'SURNAME1.txt':
then create field in 3rd main file where will be written 'SURNAME1'
```

right now i can check where my names are with this code:

```
if ('NAME1') in open('SURNAME1.txt').read():
print ("true")
```

on output i need to receive in my main file:

```
1, NAME1, SURNAME1
2, NAME2, SURNAME2
3, NAME2, SURNAME2
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: Just load them into `list` and compare.  This is way faster than keep opening the file with the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Forenames(dict):
    def __missing__ (self, key):
        return ''

from collections import defaultdict

surnames = defaultdict(list)
for fileName in ['surname1.txt', 'surname2.txt']:
    surname = fileName[:-4]
    with open(fileName) as names:
        for line in names:
            surnames[surname].append(line.strip())

forenames = Forenames()
for surname in surnames:
    for forename in surnames[surname]:
        if forenames[forename]:
            raise RuntimeError('forename previously found')
        else:
            forenames[forename] = surname

with open('names.txt') as names:
    for line in names:
        number, value = line.strip().split(', ')
        surname = forenames[value]
        print (number, value, surname)
```

Results:

```
1 Bill 
2 Egon surname2
3 Cynthia surname1
4 Colin surname2
5 James surname2
```

... with this content for `names.txt`

```
1, Bill
2, Egon
3, Cynthia
4, Colin
5, James
```

... this for `surname1.txt`

```
John
Mary
Cynthia
```

... and this for `surname2.txt`

```
Egon
Colin
James
```

First the code makes a dictionary of forenames corresponding to each 'surname'. Then it inverts this dictionary into a dictionary of surnames corresponding to forenames. This latter dictionary is constructed so that missing values for surnames are replaced with blank strings. Finally the file `names.txt` is read and parsed, and the forenames are looked up in the second dictionary.

Comment: Hello, thank You for the answer, but i dont have two files with the surnames, those files "surname1, surname2" are banch of names. So if in my main file some of the names exist in for example in surname1.txt, i need to create for them 3rd column with the name of the file , in this case "surname1". Thanks!

Comment: Code and explanation replaced.